# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa3 in position 4089 when using .csv in python

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I'm trying to import a csv file as a list of dictionaries

Here's my code error message

```
import csv

with open('Copy of Tx Export.csv') as csvfile:
    test = list(csv.DictReader(csvfile))




Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/alexandermcghee/Google Drive/PycharmProjects/Tx_Data/functionList.py", line 4, in <module>
    test = list(csv.DictReader(csvfile))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/csv.py", line 112, in __next__
    row = next(self.reader)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/codecs.py", line 321, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa3 in position 4089: invalid start byte
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What codec was used to encode your CSV file? Provide it to the `open()` call as  (the `encoding` argument).

Comment: Is there any way to find that out?

Comment: Not really, you should figure out what exported that CSV to find out what encoding was used. In the mean time, you can instruct `open()` to ignore encoding errors but you're risking missed characters, e.g.: `open("Copy of Tx Export.csv", encoding="utf-8", errors="replace")`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Since I am using csv.DictReader to open many CSV files, and I am OK to lose a few records here and there, I was able to use the  `errors="replace"` argument to skip past the row(s) / record(s) that caused the error(s).

Here's my code:

```
theCSV = r"myFile.csv"
with open(theCSV,'r', encoding='utf-8', errors="replace") as csvfile:
    fileReader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    etc..
```